# Generalized linear mixed model with time lags

Tags: time-series, generalized-linear-model, nonparametric-density, ecology

I'm attempting to understand how random variables and one fixed variable are influencing an animal population over time. The trouble I am having is that my population density estimates were only sampled every 3 years on average.

I'm trying to match those values with two other data bases that have the random variables. One random variable are values that are 10 to 40 years from the survey year and classified into two different treatments. The other variable has been sampled every year.

So this means that for one y value, there are 3 x values from one random variable that influences it because of a time lag. As for the age class of 10 to 40 years, there are numerous values that could be influencing that one density measure. I am suspecting that I need to do a generalized mixed linear model because my fixed variable is the area the surveys were performed.

Any guidance on how to go about this is greatly appreciated.